# how to print a full listview (android)

Tags: android-layout, listview, pdf, printing, adapter

my question is that  my Code can print a part from the LISTVIEW , and cant show the rest of the content . it is a LITSVIEW inside a LINEARLAYOUT. when i give the LINEARLAYOUT a big number inside the XML , then i can see the full content . 
otherwise it cant show full content. the printmanager and print adapter are working fine , i think my problem is how to to set the size of the canvas [PLZ SEE THIS IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkEZg.jpg)

it is a very useful code and am sure lot of people can find it very helpful .
the code is

//Connect to the Print Manager instance

```
public void printPDF(View view) {

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
    printManager.print("print_any_view_job_name", new ViewPrintAdapter(this,
    findViewById(R.id.nameOfLayout)), null);
```

}

public class ViewPrintAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

```
private PrintedPdfDocument mDocument;
private Context mContext;
private View mView;

public ViewPrintAdapter(Context context, View view) {
    mContext = context;
    mView = view;
}

@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes,
                     CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                     LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {

    mDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(mContext, newAttributes);

    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        callback.onLayoutCancelled();
        return;
    }

    PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo
            .Builder("print_output.pdf")
            .setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
            .setPageCount(1);

    PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
    callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
}

@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pages, ParcelFileDescriptor destination,
                    CancellationSignal cancellationSignal,
                    WriteResultCallback callback) {

    // Start the page
    PdfDocument.Page page = mDocument.startPage(0);
    // Create a bitmap and put it a canvas for the view to draw to. Make it the size of the view
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight (),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    mView.draw(canvas);
    // create a Rect with the view's dimensions.
    Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight ());
    // get the page canvas and measure it.
    Canvas pageCanvas = page.getCanvas();
    float pageWidth = pageCanvas.getWidth();
    float pageHeight = pageCanvas.getHeight();
    // how can we fit the Rect src onto this page while maintaining aspect ratio?
    float scale = Math.min(pageWidth/src.width(), pageHeight/src.height());
    float left = pageWidth / 2 - src.width() * scale / 2;
    float top = pageHeight / 2 - src.height() * scale / 2;
    float right = pageWidth / 2 + src.width() * scale / 2;
    float bottom = pageHeight / 2 + src.height() * scale / 2;
    RectF dst = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);

    pageCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, src, dst, null);
    mDocument.finishPage(page);

    try {
        mDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(
                destination.getFileDescriptor()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
        return;
    } finally {
        mDocument.close();
        mDocument = null;
    }
    callback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[]{new PageRange(0, 0)});
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i succeed to put all the LISTVIEW inside one PDF file with single page.
just set the height of the LAYOUT equal the height of the LISTVIEW ADAPTER .
i hope i can print it on a receipt printer !

```
// Gets linearlayout
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
// Gets the layout params that will allow you to resize the layout
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params1 = layout.getLayoutParams();
// Changes the height and width to the specified *pixels*

  layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```